# Image based counting algorithm to count objects on a moving conveyor

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am building a vision system which can count boxes moving on a variable speed conveyor belt.

Using open_cv and c++, I could separate the blobs and extract the respective centroids.

Now I have to increment the count variable, if the centroid crosses the cutoff boundary line.

This is where I am stuck. I tried 2 alternatives.

1. Fixing a rectangular strip where a centroid would stay for only one single frame

- But since the conveyor is multi speed, I could not fix a constant boundary value.

2. I tried something like

   ```
   centroid_prev = centroid_now;
   centroid_now = posX;
   if (centroid_now >= xLimit && centroid_prev < xLimit)
   {
       count++;
   }
   ```

- This works fine if just a single box is present on the conveyor.
- But for 2 or more blobs in same frame, I do not know how to handle using arrays for contours.

**Can you please suggest a simple counting algorithm which can compare
blob properties between previous frame and current frame even if
multiple blobs are present per frame?**

PS. Conveyor speed is around 50 boxes/second, so a lightweight algorithm will be very much appreciated else we may end up with a lower frame rate.

Comment: does a single object look the same in each frame or can it rotate etc?

Comment: It can rotate and the size may change too, sometimes small boxes may come in between.

Comment: so it is not possible to re-identify boxes between images just from shape and orientation?

Comment: Yes, that may not me possible. Because there is a greater probability for boxes to be exactly the same size, and to have the same orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the images you pasted are representative, you can easily solve this by doing some kind of tracking.
The simplest way that comes to mind is to use `goodFeaturesToTrack` and `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` to track the motion of the conveyor.
You'll probably need to do some filtering on the result, but I don't think that would be difficult, as the motion and images are very low in noise.
Once you have that motion, you can calculate for each centroid when it moved beyond a certain X threshold and count it.

With a low number of corners (<100) such as in this image, it should be fast.

Comment: Thank you Photon. I am trying to implement the suggestions. I am quite new to opencv so I am trying one thing at a time, or else I get confused.  As of now, I am working on implementing descriptor matchers, to compare coordinates as suggested by Nickie. Will update you abt the results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried matching the centroid coordinates from the previous frame with the centroids from the new frame? You can use OpenCV's [descriptor matchers](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html) for that. (The code samples all match feature vectors, but there's no reason why you shouldn't use them for coordinate matching.)

If you're worried about performance: matching 5-10 coordinate centers should be orders of magnitudes faster than finding blobs in an image.

Comment: I tried to match the centroids from previous frames, but I still get stuck when one of the box moves out of the Field of vision.

Comment: For example, in frame_3, the first 2 boxes (box_1 and box_2) have already  crossed the fov and my code compares the centroids of box_1 from frame_2 with box_3 from frame_3 thereby resulting in improper counting. Do you have any suggestion to handle this scenario.

Comment: I am quite new to opencv, so it takes a while to try new things. I used contours to find and compare centroids. Descriptor matchers seems interesting, will try that and let you know about the results. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the algorithm for arrays. It's just an extension of what you are doing - you can adjust the specifics

```
for(i=0; i<centroid.length; i++)
  centroid_prev[i] = centroid[i].posX;

for(frame j=0 to ...) {

 ... recompure centroids

for(i=0; i<centroid.length; i++) {
  centroid_now = centroid[i].posX;
  if (centroid_now >= xLimit && centroid_prev[i] < xLimit)
  {
  count++;
  }
}

for(i=0; i<centroid.length; i++)
  centroid_prev[i] = centroid[i].posX;

}// end j
```

--

If the objects can  move about (and they look about the same) you need to add additional info such as color to locate the same objects.

Comment: This did not work for scenarios when, one or more boxes moves out of the field of vision.

Comment: For example, in frame_3, the first 2 boxes (box_1 and box_2) have already crossed the fov and my code compares the centroids of box_1 from frame_2 with box_3 from frame_3 thereby resulting in improper counting. Do you have any suggestion to handle this scenario.

Comment: If the objects can move about (and they look about the same) you need to add additional info such as color to locate the same objects.